# Remove RouteVoter on a KnpMenu

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

Each bundle of the extranet is a independent application. In my menu every app is listed and I like to mark the current one depending the actual route prefix.

First the twig code in the base.html.twig:

```twig
{{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu', { 'currentClass': 'active'}) }}
```

The builder function:

```php
public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options){
  $main = $factory->createItem('root');

  foreach($this->getExtranetBundles() as $bundle){
    $main->addChild($bundle->getAcronym(), array('route' => $bundle->getRoute()));
  }

  // Current Element
  $matcher = new Matcher();
  $matcher->addVoter(new BundleVoter($this->getCurrentBundle()));
  $renderer = new ListRenderer($matcher);
  $renderer->render($main);

  return $main;
}
```

My BundleVoter class works correct and returns true if the current menu is found. But in the HTML the current element never contains the "active" class.

I read myself a bit more in the KnpMenuBundle and added some debug code in the Knp\Menu\Matcher class:

```php
public function addVoter(VoterInterface $voter)
{
    echo "add voter: " . get_class($voter);
    $this->voters[] = $voter;
}
```

And got this output:

```
add voter: AppBundle\Menu\BundleVoter
add voter: Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\RouteVoter
```

From where does the mysterious RouteVoter come from? Does it overwrite my BundleVoter selection of current elements? And how can I deactivate / overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to change the standard knp_menu class. I edited the services.yml file to the follow:

```
parameters:
    knp_menu.voter.router.class: AppBundle\Menu\BundleVoter

services:
    appbundle.menu.voter.request:
        class: AppBundle\Menu\BundleVoter
        arguments: [@service_container]
        tags:
          - { name: knp_menu.voter }
```

The class is still instantiated two times, unfortunately I have to check if the passed parameter if its empty or not. And the $container param has to be optional...

```
class BundleVoter implements VoterInterface
{
  private $container;

  public function __construct($container = null)
  {
    if($container != null)
      $this->container = $container;
  }

  public function matchItem(ItemInterface $item)
  {
    if($this->container != null){
      $bundle = $this->container->get('menubundles')->getCurrentBundle();
      if (null === $bundle || null === $item->getName()) {
        return null;
      }

      if ($item->getName() == $bundle->getAcronym()) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Please write if you found a better solution :-) Thx